# laravel - multi upload and save different filename to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to upload multiple images and save different filename to database.

I have an HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="upload_file" name="image[]" multiple/>
```

and a database table:

```
id 
image1 
image2 
image3 
image4 
image5 
created_at 
updated_at
```

Whether it can be like this?

Comment: what is the specific problem you need help with? yes you can upload 5 images and store their name in the database.

Comment: Would it be better if you separate them into different records with different ids? Like ID, Filename, Image(BLOB?), Created At, Updated At

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image[]` is an array.You can store array elements in different columns this way:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $model=new Model();
    $model->image1=$request->image[0];
    $model->image2=$request->image[1];
    $model->image3=$request->image[2];
    ...
    $model->save();
}
```

Normal way:

```
$image=$_POST['image'];
INSERT INTO table (image1,image2,image3...)VALUES('$image[0]','$image[1]','$image[2]...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct way is to make an `Image` model with a corresponding table, then you would set its relations with other models. Something like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $model = new RelatedModel(); // This is a related model example

    $images = $request->file("image.*");
    foreach($images as $uploadedImage)
    {
        $path = $uploadedImage->store('path/images', 'local'); // disk can be null, it will then use the default disk in filesystems.php
        $image = new Image();
        // A way you want to use to give the image a name
        $image->name = $this->generateName(); 
        $image->path = $path;
        // Where relatedModel is the method on Image model defining a belongsTo relation for example with RelatedModel
        $image->relatedModel()->associate($model); 
        $image->save();
    }

}
```

I don't know why you are saving the pictures the way specified in the question. But if you insist, you must add new fields

```
id | image1 | image1_name | image2 | image2_name ...
```

Then in your code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $model=new Model();

    // This is a function you would make to generate a different name than the path
    $model->image1_name = $this->generateName(); 
    $model->image1 = $request->file("image.0");->store('path/images', 'local');
    $model->image2_name = $this->generateName(); 
    $model->image2 = $request->file("image.1");->store('path/images', 'local');
    // ...etc.

    $model->save();
}
```